# convert hex ip address to dotted decimal in GDB

Tags: c, gdb

I am using GDB to debug C code, I see ip address been shown as  -

npc_srcip = 0x7fa06e7fd430, npc_dstip = 0x7fa06e7fd434. 
What is the way to convert this to decimal dotted format?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These look like pointers because they are bigger than 32 bit. You will want to dereference them probably. Then convert each byte from hex to decimal and you got your ip address.
That is something like:  `x/4ub npc_srcip` should give you the parts.

Comment: Its ipv4 address, so running - (gdb) x/4b npc->npc_srcip
0x7fa06e7fd430: -64     -88     74      3. So i need to convert each of this byte to decimal and form the ip address?

Comment: Eh, signed ... try `x/4ub` then.